# ntfs general Question

Tags: filesystems, ntfs

One week ago I got my Macbook Air [it is wonderful :-)] and as I desired, I installed (using Bootcamp) Windows in addition.  I am happy as it works fine and very sweet is that I can access the Windows partition from OS X (at least to read data, at the Moment I am trying several solutions to have write capabilities in addition) but on the second thought I've been surprised. Because OS X can simply read data on my NTFS file system without getting a password or something else, i thought it is a safe file system.

This would mean, all the data on my Computer can be read by everybody who wants even if my OS is protected with the best password, it is simply enough to attach the drive to another computer and access it. I am right? Is there a way to protect the drive?

Thanks in advance
Jo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's right, NTFS won't enforce security if you physically connect the drive to another OS or system, nor will most filesystems out there.

There's a range of options you can use, from encrypting your user dir to use TrueCrypt and other solutions to encrypt sensitive data.

There's also drives with hardware encryption available, but that'll protect you only if you're trying to attach your drive to another machine.

My personal recommendation (and that's what I do), encrypt sensitive documents.

Comment: +1 filesystem ACLs provide absolutely no protection against someone with physical access to the media.  Encryption is really the only answer, if you are concerned about your disk/computer being stolen.